# Business Continuity Plan -- How can I connect to DR Server if PROD site is completely Down

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, disaster-recovery

I have two servers in one DataCenterA (PRODUCTION SQL SERVERS AOAGs) and one server in another DatacenterB (DR BCP AOAGs).What if DataCenterA is completely Down.Now how can I let the Application stay Online.My SQL Servers has AlwaysOn Availability Groups.Can I connect to application by changing the connection string as "SQL\Instancename" in web.config file or using BCP AOAGs Listener which we created for AlwaysOn AGs BCP Listener ?
Please Guide me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have:

- 2 Datacenters
- 1 Server in Each DC
- Using SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups

Then the following happens:

- The Primary Datacenter Goes Down, Completely

How do you continue business continuity?

Assuming that the Availability Replicas are both set to Synchronous...

1. Quorum will have most likely been lost - you'll need to force quorum on the server in the DC that is still up. This can be completed a variety of ways. Powershell: `Start-ClusterNode -FixQuorum` , services: `net start clussvc /fq` , etc.
2. Connect to SQL Server now that the cluster was forced quorum. Failover the Availability Group. This will bring the listener with it. Whether Synchronous or Asynchronous is set, this can be accomplished by executing `ALTER VAILABILITY GROUP [Name] FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`
3. Test connectivity.

Depending on the settings of the listener in the windows cluster, your clients may need to flush their dns cache (to pickup the new ip if they are legacy clients).

Once the first DC comes back online we'll want to make sure to reconfigure and re-evaluate the situation.

Resources that will help you:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781257.aspx (Solutions guide for HA/DR)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn425173.aspx (MSIT case study for HA/DR)

Comment: Thank you @sean.Now that my Primary site (Two PROD SQL servers AOAGs Synchronous) are down.Now I am left over only with BCP site (SQL Server with Async AOAGs).As you said, 2.Connect to SQL Server now that the cluster was forced quorum. Failover the Availability Group. This will bring the listener with it. Whether Synchronous or Asynchronous is set, this can be accomplished by executing ALTER VAILABILITY GROUP [Name] FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS ---- From here will I be able to access Application using the BCP AOAGs Listener and Databases ?

Comment: And I have separate MSDTC resource for BCP Node.Should I make it online when I do forced manual failover to BCP node ?

Comment: First, we don't support distributed transactions (MSDTC) for availability groups in 2012/2014. Second, when we force failover all other replicas will be disconnected and their data streams paused. You'll need to manually resume the other replica at the BCP site. Yes, after the forced failover you should be able to connect to the listener.